# Why does the Matrix visualisation show 365 days in a month?

Tags: date, powerbi, data-modeling

I am seeing some very strange results in a Matrix visual showing data from a date table. I have FiscalYear and CalendarEndMonth as columns and a count of the rows in the same table as the values. All is as expected for the first fiscal year in view (2021/22), the row counts are the days in each month, but then the first month of 2022/23 is showing 365! I created a min and max date measure too and that is showing 1/4/2021 and 31/3/2022, despite 2022/23 showing on the column:

[image]

Stranger still, this happens with whatever the second year in the view is, i.e. if I include 2020/21 the counts are as expected but the first month of 2021/22 now has 365 days. There are 365 days in later years too. Also, if I move the Fiscal Year and Calendar Month to rows, everything is as expected i.e. no 365 totals:

[image]

My model is a single table, which is a date table. There is one row per date and no missing dates. I have exported the table to Excel to check it and the counts are as expected. I was using the table as part of a larger model but stripped everything out to try and diagnose the problem but no luck.

I think this must be to do with the Matrix visual as the results are as expected when I use the table visual but I am at a loss to understand this behaviour. Can anyone help? Thanks.